Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement
I'm trying to run a statement in Teradata, using DBeaver 24.2.
When I run my statement in Teradata SQL Assistant, it runs perfectly, but when I run it using DBeaver, I'm getting the following error:

Error SQL [3932] [25000]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 20.00.00.34] [Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.

This is my script:
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE BASE_MOVIMENTO_MOVEL AS (
    SELECT
        FMLD.*
    FROM
        P_MVM.VW_FAT_MVMT FMLD
    WHERE
        DT_MVMT_LNHA >= TRUNC(CAST(TO_DATE('01' || '/' || SUBSTR('202408', 5,2) || '/' || SUBSTR('202408', 0,5), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE))
        AND DT_MVMT_LNHA <= LAST_DAY(CAST(TO_DATE('01' || '/' || SUBSTR('202408', 5,2) || '/' || SUBSTR('202408', 0,5), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE))
    ) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(
        DT_MVMT_LNHA
    ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
ET;
SELECT * FROM BASE_MOVIMENTO_MOVEL;

Can anyone help me?
I tried to use BT; and ET; in each DDL statement, but it didn't work.

At a guess, it is probably executed in a single transaction, to solve this, you probably need to commit between creating the table and executing that select.

First, set tmode=ANSI.  Then select all the queries you want to execute together, and run them using Execute SQL Script  (it's alt + x, at least on windows).  Don't use Execute SQL Statement.

You need to use Execute SQL Script as @Andrew says and also be sure you are in auto-commit mode (which is the default for Dev/Test connections but not Prod connections). Or if you want to use manual commit mode then set tmode=ANSI and add COMMIT; between the statements instead of ET;. Using ET; followed by BT; in manual commit mode with tmode=TERA should also work but is generally not recommended.
